# cell value shift in row grouping excel Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

This picture show how I want to shift the cell value when the rows are grouping

[image]

I'm trying to shift the cell value of the rows that are grouped in excel, I'm using Java POI library**.

I couldn't find any method that can do the job. any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please put the picture in `SO`

Answer (score 2):

This is called indention. You have to use `CellStyle`:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
cellStyle.setIndention((short) 2);
cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```